# im need know how i used pop3 with smtp sender VB.NET 2008

Tags: vb.net

im need know how i used pop3 with smtp sender VB.NET 2008

I HAVE THE problem with that when i put the smtp yahoo and the account user and password he tell me Failure sending mail.

so plz im need the help now thanks

Comment: What are you using to send mail? What does POP3 have to do with SMTP (SMTP is for sending mail, POP3 is for downloading it)? What is the failure message that you're receiving? What are you actually trying to do? etc. Your question doesn't really make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to send smtp mail from VB.Net. AxMSMAPI.AxMAPI.Session and AxMSMAPI.AxMAPI.Messages are vb6 compatibility controls, I believe. This requires a MAPI email client on the user's system, such as Outlook.

```
Try
  MAPISession1.SignOn()
  MAPIMessages1.SessionID = MAPISession1.SessionID
  MAPIMessages1.Compose()
  MAPIMessages1.MsgNoteText = "Message Text"
  MAPIMessages1.AttachmentPathName = currentPicPath
  MAPIMessages1.AttachmentName = Path.GetFileName(currentpicpath)
  MAPIMessages1.AttachmentType = 0
  MAPIMessages1.Send(True)
  MAPISession1.SignOff()
Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox("Warning: The email was not sent. " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
End Try
```

Comment: IM NEED know how too work pop3 and smtp this too with porting